# Porting from bash to Gradle

Tags: bash, testing, build, gradle, build-automation

I have a Bash script for a project that looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

curl -LOk (url)/project.zip
mkdir project
unzip project.zip -d project
cp -rf project/assets assets
rm -rf project && rm -rf project.zip
gradle test
```

So all it does is download the archive I want from a different project, copy its assets to the current project's workspace, delete said archive and the extracted stuff I don't want, and then run a test suite to be sure everything's working. Since I use Gradle to run the test suite, I'd like to migrate everything to be 100% Gradle so that the build process can be 1) multi-platform & 2) easily managed since my build script is constantly maintained. How should I go about doing this? After some research I ran into [gradle-download-task](https://github.com/michel-kraemer/gradle-download-task); would that help handle the download segment, or is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways of doing it:

**First** (not a cross platform approach)

Run your script directly from gradle (without running tests in it - it can be defined via task dependency in `build.gradle` itself):

```
task download1(type: Exec) {
   executable 'sh'
   args 'download.sh'
}
```

**Second**

Use groovy + gradle magic:

```
task download2 << {
   def file = project.file('sample2.zip')   
   def out = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file))
   out << new URL(zipUrl).openStream()
   out.close()
   project.copy {
      from zipTree(file)
      into 'project2'
   }
   project.copy {
      from project.file('project2/assets')
      into 'assets2'
   }
   project.file('project2').deleteDir()
   project.file('sample2.zip').delete()
}
```

**Third**

Use the plugin you found:

```
task download3(type: Download) {
    def destination = new File(rootDir, 'sample3.zip')
    src zipUrl
    dest destination
    doLast {
      project.copy {
         from zipTree(destination)
         into 'project3'
      }
      project.copy {
         from project.file('project3/assets')
         into 'assets3'
      }
      project.file('project3').deleteDir()
      project.file('sample3.zip').delete()
    }
}
```

Complete example can be found [here](https://github.com/Opalo/stackoverflow/tree/master/28650976).

Comment: Just a quick question; how would I call that `gradle test` command from this script? The `test` task can also accept some parameters, and running a simple `commandLine` call makes Gradle unhappy.

Comment: Jest run `gradle test` from command line. You need to define a dependency between test and download task. Read about it.

Comment: Alright thanks! Just one more; is there a way to replace the second `project.copy` to a statement that moves from directory a into directory b?

Comment: Not 100% sure with gradle but you can move files with java/groovy.